# How can I crop Qt window from both sides?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a Qt window where all widgets have been inserted in a centralwidget, therefore when the window is resized the widgets size do not change (Original Window):

[image: Original Window]

Sometimes, I do not need to see some widgets on the right side or left side, So I try to crop the Windows as those widget are not visible (Right-cropped window):

[image: Right-cropped window]

However, this is just true for the widgets on the right side of Qt window and when I try to crop the window from the left, the widgets on the left are not hidden (Right-cropped window):

[image: Right-cropped window]

Is there any way/trick to be able to crop from the left edge as the PushButton1 is not visible?

Comment: Are you **really** sure about this approach? I find it very uncomfortable and absolutely unintuitive, from the user experience perspective.

Comment: Yes, I really want it

Comment: Do you realize that: 1. if for *any* reason the window is resized *not* by the user, it's impossible to decide what side of the window should be "cropped" (which will become arbitrary, possibly making the interface even more unintuitive), and 2. hiding part of the UI and *not* providing any way to access it (using scroll bars, for example), is a very, *very bad* practice?

Comment: This *very, very bad practices* are just used when a programmer is codding for himself :D

Comment: Have you tried just removing the buttons from the widget? You can even keep the button instances around so they don't have to be instantiated again desired. Could also try making them invisible but I suspect you will then have unwanted padding on the sides of the window because they still reserve a column in the layout.

Comment: @DeanJohnson I suppose that your suggestion won't be what the OP is asking about: hiding buttons results in instantly resizing the layout to adjust to the current visible widgets, which might also result in a recursion.

Comment: @Kim I have to admit, even if I still believe that your request is *not* good from the UX perspective, I can understand your request and I actually think that it would be interesting to find a good solution. That said, unfortunately, right now I cannot find a *valid* approach to do so, due to some Qt "limitations" (which are actually intended as cross-platform features). The most important problem is that, as already said, there's no *direct* and *safe* way to know "what" border of the widget has actually caused the resize, especially because there are some events that happen when the widget->

Comment: ->is "mapped" for the first time, and those events (the amount, and the order) might change for *a lot* of reasons: the operating system, the *version* of the OS, and possible plugins/background apps that provide custom resizing. For example: what would happen if the screen resolution changes and the window is maximized? Not only you cannot know the actual screen geometry (especially for multiple screen setups), but you cannot even decide "where" the geometry of the whole widgets would be mapped to.

Comment: Right now I can only suggest you to look up for a [scoll()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#scroll) implementation, along with a custom and internal pseudo-sizegrip implementation along with a `FramelessWindowHint` flag and a fixed size for the widget, starting from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62812752

Comment: @musicamante _there's no direct and safe way to know "what" border of the widget has actually caused the resize_ This is not as complicated as you think. When a window is resized, its width and/or height will change. (That's trivial.) If its x position changes as well, it was resized moving the left border. If its y position changes as well, it was resized moving the top border. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit that I was not fully sure whether I had fully understood the intention of OP. Though, the comment of [@musicamente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65412975/how-can-i-crop-qt-window-from-both-sides#comment115657038_65412975) raised my attention:

> there's no direct and safe way to know "what" border of the widget has actually caused the resize

I believe that this is not so complicated. To prove me right or wrong, I just started an MCVE to check this out.

Thereby, I started from the assumption that a resize by dragging the left and/or top window border should result in changed window coordinates as well. So, it should be possible to determine this, and to keep the positions of the resp. window children constant in relation to the desktop (instead of the top/left window corner as it is usual in Qt).

This can be done by simply compensating movements of the window by negative movements of the resp. window children. This may (or may not) be limited to window resizing only.
(If it's applied to window movement as well this results in another funny effect making the window a peephole-like.)

The placement of child windows is in Qt usually subject of layout managers (derived from `QLayout`). While there are a variety of layout managers built-in (which cover the needs of the daily business), there is also the option of to make a [Custom Layout Manager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#how-to-write-a-custom-layout-manager). Another option is to not to use any layout manager but placing and resizing child widgets directly. To keep the MCVE simple and short, I used the latter option.

While I was fiddling with this I noticed some effects I was not aware about before and tried to handle this respectively.

- When the current window position is retrieved in a `resizeEvent()` it provides the old position. The current position cannot be retrieved from the call data (of type `QResizeEvent`). The solution is to defer the compensating child widget movements until the processing of resizing is completed. This can be conveniently achieved with a single-shot timer (with delay 0).
- When dragging the left or top window border, the `resizeEvent()` was accompanied by a `moveEvent()`. (Makes sense to me somehow.) So, I have to distinguish `moveEvents()` resulting from window movement from `moveEvents()` resulting from window resizing. I noticed that (in my case) the `resizeEvent()`s were always sent before the `moveEvent()`s. In good hope, that this might be something reliable, I used a flag to ignore `moveEvent()`s from a `resizeEvent()` until my deferred processing of child movement.

(I must admit that Python is only my second (or third) language while my first is C++. So, I wrote a proof-of-concept in C++, deferring the port to Python/PyQt until later.)

This is what I ended up with:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class Window: public QWidget {
  private:
    QVector<QWidget*> _pQWidgetsMove;
    int _x, _y;
    bool _updateXY = true;

  public:
    Window(QWidget *pQParent = nullptr): QWidget(pQParent) { }
    virtual ~Window() = default;

    Window(const Window&) = delete;
    Window& operator=(const Window&) = delete;

    void setMoveWidgets(QVector<QWidget*> pQWidgetsMove)
    {
      _pQWidgetsMove = pQWidgetsMove;
    }

  protected:
    virtual void showEvent(QShowEvent *pQEvent) override;
    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *pQEvent) override;
    virtual void moveEvent(QMoveEvent *pQEvent) override;
};

void Window::showEvent(QShowEvent *pQEvent)
{
  QWidget::showEvent(pQEvent);
  _x = x(); _y = y();
}

void Window::moveEvent(QMoveEvent* pQEvent)
{
  QWidget::moveEvent(pQEvent);
  if (_updateXY) {
    _x += pQEvent->pos().x() - pQEvent->oldPos().x();
    _y += pQEvent->pos().y() - pQEvent->oldPos().y();
  }
}

void Window::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* pQEvent)
{
  QWidget::resizeEvent(pQEvent);
  _updateXY = false;
  QTimer::singleShot(0, // 0 ms -> idle callback
    [this, x = x(), y = y()]() {
      for (QWidget* pQWidget : _pQWidgetsMove) {
        pQWidget->move(pQWidget->x() + _x - x, pQWidget->y() + _y - y);
      }
      _x = x; _y = y;
      _updateXY = true;
    });
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // config GUI
  const int wMain = 320, hMain = 240; // initial size of main window
  const int nBtns = 4; // number of buttons
  // setup GUI
  Window qWinMain;
  qWinMain.setWindowTitle("Fun with Resize");
  qWinMain.resize(wMain, hMain);
  QPushButton qBtns[nBtns];
  { int i = 0;
    for (QPushButton& qBtn : qBtns) {
      const int xBtn = i * wMain / nBtns, wBtn = wMain / nBtns;
      qBtn.setParent(&qWinMain);
      qBtn.move(xBtn, 0);
      qBtn.resize(wBtn, hMain);
      qBtn.setText(QString("Button %1").arg(i + 1));
      ++i;
    }
  }
  QCheckBox qTglStick("Stick Buttons to Desktop", &qWinMain);
  qTglStick.move(2, 2);
  qWinMain.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qTglStick, &QCheckBox::toggled,
    [&](bool checked) {
      QVector<QWidget*> pQWidgetsMove;
      if (checked) {
        for (QPushButton& qBtn : qBtns) pQWidgetsMove.push_back(&qBtn);
      }
      qWinMain.setMoveWidgets(pQWidgetsMove);
    });
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output (Windows, Visual Studio 2019):
[image: snapshot of testQWindowResize.exe on Windows 10 (animated)]

This doesn't look that bad.

There is a little shaking in the buttons while the window is resized with dragging the top and/or left border. I assume that this results from the sequential processing of events resulting from calls of `QWidget::move()`. I have no real idea how to work-around this. (Suppressing `paintEvent()`s for a resp. duration?) So, I decided to live with this for now.

While it's working on Windows, how about Linux?

So, I rebuilt and tested in Debian (in a VM).

Output (Debian, g++ 8.3.0):
[image: snapshot of ./testQWindowResize on Debian 4.19 (animated)]

---

Finally, the port of the above MCVE to Python3 / PyQt5:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QCheckBox

class Window(QWidget):

  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.widgetsMove = list()
    self.x, self.y = (0, 0)
    self.updateXY = True

  def setMoveWidgets(self, widgets):
    self.widgetsMove = widgets
    self.x, self.y = QWidget.x(self), QWidget.y(self)

  def moveEvent(self, event):
    QWidget.moveEvent(self, event)
    if self.updateXY:
      self.x += event.pos().x() - event.oldPos().x()
      self.y += event.pos().y() - event.oldPos().y()

  def moveWidgets(self, xOld, yOld):
    for widget in self.widgetsMove:
      widget.move( \
        widget.x() + self.x - xOld, \
        widget.y() + self.y - yOld)
    self.x, self.y = xOld, yOld
    self.updateXY = True

  def resizeEvent(self, event):
    QWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)
    self.updateXY = False
    QTimer.singleShot(0, \
      lambda x = QWidget.x(self), y = QWidget.y(self): \
        Window.moveWidgets(self, x, y))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print("Qt Version: {}".format(QT_VERSION_STR))
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  # config GUI
  wMain, hMain = 320, 240
  nBtns = 4
  # setup GUI
  qWinMain = Window()
  qWinMain.setWindowTitle("Fun with Resize (PyQt5)")
  qWinMain.resize(wMain, hMain)
  qBtns = list()
  for i in range(0, nBtns):
    xBtn = i * wMain / nBtns
    wBtn = wMain / nBtns
    qBtn = QPushButton(qWinMain)
    qBtn.move(xBtn, 0)
    qBtn.resize(wBtn, hMain)
    qBtn.setText("Button {}".format(i + 1))
    qBtns.append(qBtn)
  qTglStick = QCheckBox("Stick Buttons to Desktop", qWinMain)
  qTglStick.move(2, 2)
  qWinMain.show()
  # install signal handlers
  qTglStick.toggled.connect(lambda checked: \
    qWinMain.setMoveWidgets(qBtns if checked else list()))
  # runtime loop
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output (Debian, Python3, PyQt5):
[image: snapshot of ./testQWindowResize on Debian 4.19, Python3, PyQt5 (animated)]

Comment: The concept is almost what I was thinking of, and my "preoccupied" comments were exactly about the delays and timing of both resize *and* move events. There are many issues at hand: for instance, on Linux the management of geometry changes can be different according to the window manager (for instance, the moveEvent is often sent *at the end* of the movement), and there's always the issue of the frame geometry. I'll check your code tomorrow, anyway. And there's still the issue of system-requested events, and the fact that all this can only be achieved if the window has been *already* mapped.

Comment: @musicamante I wouldn't use the code in production. I saw this rather as a pre-X-mas-last-office-day-puzzle. Not to mention that it provided me a "serious" reason to install X11 in my Debian VM. (Before I was working in console only - somehow missing the X-term I was used to in the past.) :-)